# Capturing all output from piping input into a cli program

Tags: linux, pipe

When I do something like:

```
$ echo "print \"test\"" | python
```

I want:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> print "test"
test
```

Instead of:

```
test
```

Is there some way to capture all the prompts in the stdout?

Comment: I don't think this is related to the capturing of "all" output - it's a matter of running python interactively - which you can do by adding the `-i` option: `echo "print \"test\"" | python -i`

Comment: How about `script` command?

Comment: @steeldriver I just tried it and it's still missing the ">>> print ..." input line. Is there something more generic to work with other interactive cli programs, not just python?

Comment: Well - there's [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine all the suggestions made in comments like so, with a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) mixed in:

```
$ script -c 'python -i <<< "print \"test\""'
Script started, file is typescript
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 13 2018, 13:06:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test
>>>
Script done, file is typescript
```

Which will log the above into a file called, `typescript`:

```
$ cat typescript
Script started on Tue 21 Aug 2018 12:19:50 AM EDT
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 13 2018, 13:06:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test
>>>

Script done on Tue 21 Aug 2018 12:19:50 AM EDT
```

The above method works like so:

- `script -c`'...'`- runs the commands in single quotes in`script`and logs the output to the file`typescript`
- `python -i <<< "...."` - runs Python in interactive mode, passing a command, `"...."` in as a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)
- `"print \"test\""` - command to run as a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

#### typescript with escape sequences

If you find that your resulting `typescript` file contains escape sequences such as:

```
ESC[34mRPMsESC[39;49mESC[0m
ESC[34mRPMs_fpmESC[39;49mESC[0m
ESC[34mansibleESC[39;49mESC[0m
```

You can use `less -R` or `less -r` to view these:

```
$ less -R somefile
RPMs
RPMs_fpm
ansible
```

#### References

- [here documents - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: Thanks, "script" looks like what I want. However, the typescript output file has some weird characters. Examples are "\u001b]0;" "\u001b[00m" "u001b[01;34m". Any suggestions on how to clean it up?

Comment: That's output based on your `$PROMPT` being colorized. Those are escape characters which make define what colors to show your shell's prompt. Try viewing the file with `less -R`, this will properly display these escape sequences.